# Getting CSS columns to bunch on the left instead of spreading out

Tags: html, css

How do I get CSS columns to not spread out but instead bunch on the left

What I get

[image]

What I want

[image]

Example

```css
body {
  background-color: #c3dbff;
}
.cols {
  columns: 250px;  /* want however many 250px columns will fit */
}
.thing {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 240px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  
  
  /* below just to make it clear the order of children in the columns */
  color: white;
  display: inline-grid;
  place-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 50pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="cols">
  <div class="thing" style="height: 200px;">1</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 200px;">2</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 290px;">3</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 280px;">4</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 200px;">5</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 230px;">6</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 260px;">7</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 210px;">8</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 280px;">9</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 230px;">10</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 260px;">11</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 210px;">12</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 200px;">13</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 270px;">14</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 220px;">15</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 260px;">16</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 250px;">17</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 290px;">18</div>
</div>
```

CSS only.

Things I tried,

- setting `column-width: 250px`. ❌
- setting the outer container to `display: inline-block;` ❌
- setting the outer container to `margin: 0 auto 0 0` ❌
- setting `column-gap: 10px` ❌
- setting `display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap` ❌

  This doesn't work because in order to wrap I'd have to give the flex box a height, otherwise it has no idea it needs to wrap. That's different that `columns` which will figure out height after figuring out how many columns.

One thing that makes it hard to find an answer is most results about `columns` are not about the css [`columns` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) but about columns in tables, or grids, or flexbox

PS: No, I'm not trying to do a masonry layout out. I want the items to go down the first column, then flow into the second (vs masonry where they flow to the right first and then fill in the shortest column. not looking for that).

Comment: Someone voted to close as "not reproducible"? [It repos in the example in the question for me, Chrome 103](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNpVj.jpg)

Comment: `No, I'm not trying to do a masonry layout out. I want the items to go down the first column, then flow into the second` you can't achieve this without using javascript

Comment: @LS_, it's what they're already doing in the live example above.

Comment: Whatever the settings for columns it insists on sharing out any leftover space between the columns. So columns: 240px and column-gap: 10px gives the look, but the columns are sometimes wider so I guess this isn't an acceptable answer?  I think a few lines of Javascript could do it, would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your items has fixed sizes so you can use CSS grid to fix this. The trick is to create as many columns with fixed width as possible and span all of them using `grid-column: 1/-1`

```css
body {
  background-color: #c3dbff;
}


.wrapper {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,250px); /* same as column width */
  gap:10px; /* same as column gap */
}

.cols {
  columns: 250px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  grid-column:1/-1; /* take all the columns of the grid*/
}

.thing {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%; /* use 100% and rely on the gap */
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  color: white;
  display: inline-grid;
  place-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 50pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="cols">
    <div class="thing" style="height: 200px;">1</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 200px;">2</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 290px;">3</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 280px;">4</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 200px;">5</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 230px;">6</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 260px;">7</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 210px;">8</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 280px;">9</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 230px;">10</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 260px;">11</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 210px;">12</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 200px;">13</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 270px;">14</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 220px;">15</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 260px;">16</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 250px;">17</div>
    <div class="thing" style="height: 290px;">18</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So this kinda works? But it does something strange (which column seems to do to). If I put less items (like 6) and I make the window wide (5-6 columns of space) and I make the window short so some items are cutoff at the bottom, I'd have expected it to move the cutoff items into columns. Instead the items are cutoff even though there'd be plenty of space for all of them if it put them in the available columns on the right: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fImG5.jpg

Comment: @samanthaj that's related to the column algorithm. I don't know how it works exactly but I  think it's not the same cross browser. If you try different browsers you will probably get different results

Comment: sigh... you're right. Does what I want in Firefox and Safari but not Chrome

Comment: Filed a bug: Let's hope they decide to fix it. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1341644

Comment: Interesting, if I understand correctly, Chrome is saying FF and Safari are wrong here. They said set `orphans: 1; widows: 1;` and if I do that it works and further, the spec says they default to 2  See: [orphans](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/orphans), [widows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/widows) so I wonder if FF and Safari are actually wrong here

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

Actually this solution doesn't work. The problem is just because the column size is N and the outer size is N * 3 does not mean the browser will chose to make 3 columns. For example, if there are only 2 items it will make 2 columns because why make 3? But when it makes 2 it ends up distributing the space. So this isn't a solution AFAICT.

### Previous answer:

I did think of one poor solution. If [container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries) worked then I could make

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then do queries on `outer` to force inner to only be multiples of the size I want the columns.

Since I don't have container queries, then I can use media queries. It kind of sucks because I can't use calc and it only works if the out container can be fit to the page.

```css
body {
  background-color: #c3dbff;
  margin: 0;
}
.cols {
  columns: 250px;  /* want however many 250px columns will fit */
  column-gap: 0px;
}
.thing {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 240px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  
  /* below just to make it clear the order of children in the columns */
  color: white;
  display: inline-grid;
  place-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 50pt;
}

@media (max-width: 2249px) { .cols { width: 2000px; } }
@media (max-width: 1999px) { .cols { width: 1750px; } }
@media (max-width: 1749px) { .cols { width: 1500px; } }
@media (max-width: 1499px) { .cols { width: 1250px; } }
@media (max-width: 1249px) { .cols { width: 1000px; } }
@media (max-width: 999px) { .cols { width: 750px;   } }
@media (max-width: 749px) { .cols { width: 500px;   } }
@media (max-width: 499px) { .cols { width: 250px;  margin-right: 10px; } }
```

```html
<div class="cols">
  <div class="thing" style="height: 200px;">1</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 200px;">2</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 290px;">3</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 280px;">4</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 200px;">5</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 230px;">6</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 260px;">7</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 210px;">8</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 280px;">9</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 230px;">10</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 260px;">11</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 210px;">12</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 200px;">13</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 270px;">14</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 220px;">15</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 260px;">16</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 250px;">17</div>
  <div class="thing" style="height: 290px;">18</div>
</div>
```

Apparently, at least in Chrome, when the column goes to a single column the margin-bottom setting is ignored.

Answer (score -2):

try using display flex. set up justify-content to flex-start, align items to the centre and flex-wrap to wrap. and give a justifiable width and avoid using inline styles.

Comment: flex won't solve this